# Is there a way to take inconsistent time data (x-value) into hourly data and give an approximate y-value using a line graph?

Tags: excel, time

I have the data below and I just want the "Date" to be hourly (17:00, 18:00, 19:00, 20:00) and the "Value" to be approximated based off current values. I'd like to automatically generate a list of values.
[Data found below]

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/61Bv7.png]

Thanks!

Comment: Hi, Welcome to SO.. Have you tried trendlines? .. Or calculating exponential moving average (EMA) in a different column ?

Comment: Well, you can use vlookup() multiple times to collect the first result smaller than the x value and the next larger, then collect the corresponding y results and a quick calculation will do.

Comment: I ended up using an exponential trendline and used that equation to develop hourly values. Thank you!